# Fetch failing with ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS with Shopify rest api

Tags: shopify, shopify-api

I'm calling Shopify REST API from within my app to a development store but `fetch` is failing with `net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` on Chrome.

My app is running on a local machine and I'm using `ngrok` for tunneling.

```
const orders_url = 'https://{store-name}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-10/orders.json?status=any';
```

```
async function getOrders() {
    try {
      const resp = await fetch(orders_url, {
        credentials: 'include',
        mode: 'no-cors'
      });
      console.log(resp);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
```

Using GraphQL on the other hand works, any ideas as to why the above `fetch` calling failing ?

Comment: Are you passing the access token to the header since I don't see it in your request? You need the `x-shopify-access-token` in your header.

Comment: I'm using `credentials: 'include'` in the fetch call which is sending locally saved credentials. The same is used by GraphQL client also which is working fine.

Comment: If you are getting constant redirect this means that you are redirected to the login page and back again, this means that the `credentials: 'include'` is not working. Are you sure that it works for GraphQL (the ADMIN graphql, not the StoreFront GraphQL)? It's mentioned in their docs that it's required to use the `x-shopify-access-token` in the header.

Comment: Yes the current scaffolded app that is generated by `shopify-cli` has only `credentials: 'include'` in the Apollo client in `_app.js` file. Also the GraphQL us working working for ADMIN only, I'm able to get orders. `const client = new ApolloClient({
  fetch: fetch,
  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: "include",
  },
});`

Comment: It even says here - https://shopify.dev/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/fetch-data-with-apollo#configure-apollo-client. Is it possible that this works for GraphQL but not for `fetch` ?

Comment: You are using `koa-shopify-graphql-proxy` for this where this package adds the header for your, see the SRC code here: https://github.com/Shopify/quilt/blob/master/packages/koa-shopify-graphql-proxy/src/shopify-graphql-proxy.ts If you are using `fetch` you need to do this manually. Once again you **need** the `x-shopify-access-token` in order for your request to be processed. This is a requirement not a recommendation for the requests. The only way to not include it is if you are using a private app.

Comment: I'm using a private app only. Secondly, the code you shared is referring to the server part of the app, while the `_app.js` file is for the frontend part and it is directly using ApolloClient from apollo-boost `import ApolloClient from "apollo-boost";`. Also, if I directly put the `orders_url` on the browser, I do get results because browser sends cookies along with the request but doesn't set any header, but doing the same from `fetch` fails.

Comment: Your backend is handling the GraphQL request, you can't make admin graphql request from the front-end without back-end handling or to be more precise if you are able to make those request from the front-end this is huge security risk in your app and you should fix it. If you are using a private app then the access token is the password or you can use a modified URL to get the orders, but once again this should not be done from the front-end. If you still insist that you don't need the header... good luck with your journey, hope it's a success, I can't provide you any additional guidance here.